# QField - Sub menus in input form for input fields

Tags: qgis

I just discovered QField and I amazed by its features! Now I am trying to create a project that will fit my needs and have come quite far. I just have one questing on adding features in the app:

When adding a feature in the Qfield App in my project, everything is on one page and I have to scroll down in order to reach all input fields. This can be quite tedious while working in the field.

In the documentation and the demo project, that follows when downloading Qfield from Play store (offline_bees.qgs), the input is split up into sub-menus which you can reach by scrolling sideways (see image). This is much more effective than having everything on one page and having to scroll downwards. Unfortunately, I haven't found out how you can split your feature into such sub-menus as seen here. I have played a bit around with the available input widgets in the attribute form, to no avail.

I have also read the available documentation for Qfield 1.0 multiple times, but since I am neither a frequent user of QGIS nor a programmer, it is a bit challenging for me to understand the instructions (*https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/vector-layers.html*). Does it have something to do with the Relation Widget or Relation Reference?

I am thankful if somebody could point me in the right direction.

[image: Sub menus when adding features to object]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I didn't play around enough. I found out how to solve my problem. Here are the instructions

In QGis while preparing the project for QField:

1. Go to layer properties/ attribute forms
2. Set to "Drag and drop designer" (I failed to find this at first)
3. Create groups (these will be the sub menus) with the "+" button
4. Drag and drop your fields into the created groups

[image: Instructions]